# Avro schema not possible for json containing dash

Tags: apache-nifi

My input Json fieldnames contain dash.
ex: "Last-Name" : "Doe"

When I pass this json to Infer Avro Schema processor, it is failing telling me "Illegal character in:Last-Name"

I also noticed that using the dash in AvroSchemaRegistry, does not compile and ultimately does not allow to enable the service.

I tried escaping the dash with "\" but still does not work.
I am on 1.4.0 version.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

A dash is not a valid character for Avro names (see the [spec here](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html#names)). As a possible workaround for NiFi 1.4.0, you can use underscores instead of dashes. If this is not a viable workaround, then as of NiFi 1.5.0 ([NIFI-4612](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4612)) you can disable name validation so it will not complain about the dashes.